# How to use ViewUserControl in "Site.Master" page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have "TopHeader.ascx" (ViewUserControl) as follows:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TopHeader.ascx.cs" Inherits="Sample.Web.CMS.Navigation.TopHeader" %>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <span class="flow-text selected-menu-option">
                <%
                    var s = Model.FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsSelected);
                    s = s ?? Model[0];
                %>
                <%= s.Caption %>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

public partial class TopHeader : ViewUserControl<List<MenuItem>>
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

In _Layout.cshtml, I have the following and it works perfectly fine:

```
<body>
    @Html.Partial("~/Navigation/TopHeader.ascx", new List<MenuItem>() { new MenuItem() { Caption = "Constituents", IsSelected = true}, new MenuItem() { Caption = "Fund Raising" }, new MenuItem() { Caption = "Orders" }, new MenuItem() { Caption = "Products" }, new MenuItem() { Caption = "Reporting" } })

</body>
```

Now, I would like to use the same "TopHeader.ascx" in "Site.Master" which is defined as follows:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Sample.Web.CMS.SiteMaster" %>
```

Code-behind

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
...
}
```

How do I use "TopHeader.ascx" in "Site.master".  How do I instantiate the control with some (menu) data (as I did in MVC View at the top)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Site.master` add basically the same code as you had in `_Layout.cshtml` except for two changes:

1. In the WebForms view engine you use `<%: whatever %>` instead of `@whatever`.
2. Make the master page be an MVC ViewMasterPage

So change the master page to be:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    ...
}
```

And use this code to render the partial:

```
<%: Html.Partial("~/Navigation/TopHeader.ascx",
    new List<MenuItem>() {
        new MenuItem() { Caption = "Constituents", IsSelected = true },
        new MenuItem() { Caption = "Fund Raising" },
        new MenuItem() { Caption = "Orders" },
        new MenuItem() { Caption = "Products" },
        new MenuItem() { Caption = "Reporting" } })
%>
```

Comment: If I switch from MasterPage to ViewMasterPage, apart from the benefits of having MVC helpers in master page, are there any drawbacks of using it?  Do we still have support to full page/control life cycle along with ViewState in ViewMasterPage?